# What is the minimum ratio to consider the data set as balanced for the classification algorithm?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, pandas

Can I consider 20% / 80% as a balanced dataset?

My target variable ratio is 62% and 37%. I hope It is a balanced dataset. Please let me know if I am wrong.

However, I would like to know, what is the minimum ratio to consider the data set as balanced for the classification algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [table](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/construct/sampling-splitting/imbalanced-data) for 'degree of imbalance' for a binary classification problem. If you have multiple classes in your data set, I'd assume that if any of the classes deviates with a similar degree as explained in that link, you have an imbalanced data set (or, at the very least, imbalanced representation of *that* minority class):

| Degree of imbalance | Proportion of Minority Class |
| --- | --- |
| Mild | 20-40% of the data set |
| Moderate | 1-20% of the data set |
| Extreme | <1% of the data set |